# How to create a basic function in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Create a function named NameFormat. The function has three input parameters. The first is expected to be a 'F' or a 'L', the second and third parameters are strings which we expect to be the last and first names. Use a varchar(25) for the second and third parameter. The function returns a string which is a formatted name. Assuming the last name will never be null:

If the first argument is 'F', then the name is formatted as firstName lastName.
If the first argument is not 'F', then the name is formatted as lastName, firstName.
If the first name is a null, then return only the last name

Here is my function which is not correct. Can someone please troubleshoot this function please:

```
   Drop function if exists a_testbed.NameFormat # 
CREATE FUNCTION a_testbed.NameFormat(
  p_mode char(1), lastname varchar(25), firstname varchar(25)) 
RETURNS varchar(52)
BEGIN 
DECLARE v_name varchar(52); 
  if p_mode = 'F' then       
    Set v_name = concat('firstname',' ','lastname');    
elseif p_mode = 'L' then       
    Set v_name = concat('lastname',',','firstname'); 
elseif firstname = null then
    Set v_name = lastname;
end if;  
Return v_name;  
end; # 

Sample Output Should Be:
a_testbed.nameFormat('F', 'Smith', 'John') # returns John Smith
a_testbed.nameFormat('L', 'McDermott', 'Annie') # returns McDermott, Annie
a_testbed.nameFormat('L', 'McDermott', null)# returns McDermott
```

Comment: probably don't need to put the (52) after the varchar in the return statement

Comment: You may need to set the delimiter before the create using "delimiter #'

Comment: i set the delimtiter beforehand, but still not working. Shouldn't I be able to test the function using a_testbed.nameFormat('F', 'Smith', 'John') #

Comment: Please stop grabbing random tags. If your question is about MySQL, what does it have to do with functional or procedural programming? Please read the descriptions of the tags before you add them to your questions. Picking random ones help no one, including you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First delimiter #, second, logic has problem, third, should be "is null", not '= null'. And Set v_name = lastname . like this:

```
Drop function if exists a_testbed.NameFormat;
delimiter #
CREATE FUNCTION a_testbed.NameFormat(
p_mode char(1), lastname varchar(25), firstname varchar(25))
RETURNS varchar(52)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_name varchar(52);
if p_mode = 'F' then
    Set v_name = concat(firstname,' ',lastname);
elseif p_mode = 'L' then
    if firstname is null then
        Set v_name = lastname;
    else
        Set v_name = concat(lastname,',',firstname);
    end if;
end if;
Return v_name;
end #

select a_testbed.nameFormat('F', 'Smith', 'John');
select a_testbed.nameFormat('L', 'McDermott', 'Annie');
select a_testbed.nameFormat('L', 'McDermott', null);
```